# Skip logging Celery results

Tags: python, logging, celery, celery-task

I have a small webapp, written in Python using Flask. Some endpoints I have, require long execution times (~60 s +). The solution is to return task ids instantly, while starting up a Celery task in the background.

Everything works fine as it is. I have redirected the logging of Celery to a file and that is working great. The result that the task return is a huge data structure that later will be processed and potentially returned to the end-user. However, I have a small issue with the logging of the results. When celery finish a task it also logs the results of it. In my case, the previously mentioned, huge data structure. This is making the logfile harder to read and unnecessarily big.

**Is it possible to only log that the task finished, the state of it and time it took?**

Something like this:

```
[2017-02-06 15:12:01,286: INFO/PoolWorker-6] Task <task_name> succeeded in 60s
```

**Not** like this:

```
[2017-02-06 15:12:01,286: INFO/PoolWorker-6] Task <task_name> succeeded in 60s <very long string, potentially thousands of rows>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change celery worker log level to higher then `INFO` with:

```
celery ... --loglevel ERROR
```

see more from [doc](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html).